# My functions are correct but i'm having trouble in calling them and assigning them value of correct data types

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program is to obtain the sum of three numbers but if any number is [13,14,17,18,19] then it's value shall become zero(0) and then the sum shall be calculated. If not the sum shall be calculated normally

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):

    return fix_teen(a) + fix_teen(b) + fix_teen(c)

def fix_teen(n):

    if n [13,14,17,18,19]:
        return 0
    else:
        return n

a=input("enter 1st no : ")
b=input("enter 2nd no : ")
c=input("enter 3rd no : ")
res = no_teen_sum(a,b,c)
print(res)
```

It shows a type error

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Your problem is with this line `if n [13,14,17,18,19]:`. Additionally, you are trying to check string input versus an array of `int`s. That will always equate to `False`. Changing your `input`s to `a = int(input("enter 1st no : "))` would change your input to an int. If you want to check membership, the syntax is `if n in [13,14,17,18,19]:`

Comment: you title is misleading, your function is incorrect as pointed out by @Axe319